# display data from multiple state in flatlist react native

Tags: firebase, react-native, react-native-flatlist

I am fetching data from two collection from firestore. and set data as two state in componentDidUpdate(). now I want to display those state as flatlist data as data props of flatlist. how can I Achive this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the FlastList data prop you can send something like [...state1, ...state2]

```
<FlatList data={[...state1, ...state2]} renderItem={renderItem} />
```